Using C++20 Concepts on template-class as public interface - GCC issue beyond CWG 1836 - satisfaction value of atomic constraint changed false -> true
Today I was experimenting with C++20 Concepts for defining public interfaces. I came across the special treatment for template-classes described by Gianluca Delfino and tried his proposals. While the given code examples are not up-to-date for the current standard, I also came across the already and well known clang issue regarding CWG 1836.
Nevertheless, Gianluca Delfino is showcasing two approaches at the bottom of his article to check a template-class efficiently against a concept: either directly (works properly for GCC and Clang; in my example template-class A) or via subclass constructor constraint (not working in clang due to the bug; in my example template-class B).
I made a third, more or less minimal example, combining both approaches (in my example template-class C) -> godbolt:
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept Interface = requires(T& t)
{
    { t.f() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<class T>
struct IInterface {
    IInterface() requires(Interface<T>) = default;
};

template<class T>
struct A {
    A() requires(Interface<A<T>>) = default;
    void f();
};

template<class T>
struct B : IInterface<B<T>> {
    void f();
};

template<class T>
struct C : IInterface<C<T>> {
    C() requires(Interface<C<T>>) = default;
    void f();
};

void f()
{
  A<int>{}; // works for GCC and Clang
  B<int>{}; // works only for GCC
  C<int>{}; // error: satisfaction value of atomic constraint changed from 'false' to 'true'
}

I do not get why GCC complains for C:

<source>:4:21: error: satisfaction value of atomic constraint 'requires(T& t) {{t->f()} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::same_as<, void>];} [with T = C]' changed from 'false' to 'true'
[...]
note: satisfaction value first evaluated to 'false' from here
26 | struct C : IInterface<C> {

In my opinion, if A<int>{}; works, and B<int>{}; works as well, I would assume the "combination" of both, i.e. C<int>{}; should work as well.
Could someone please enlighten me about this?
